# Late payment of corporation tax UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, corporation

I am hoping to hear from anyone who has experience being a single person Ltd company in the UK who has ever paid their corporation tax late by prior arrangement with HMRC i.e. letting them know I may have trouble paying.

Apparently [this is in option](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/ct/managing/pay-repay/cant-pay.htm) but I have heard horror stories that asking HMRC to pay late will trigger a tax investigation into my personal tax affairs.

Can anyone confirm if this is the case? My Accountants are saying that they cannot advise on this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think my case will answer your question to the extent you require, but I have paid corporation tax late before by a few days and wasn't fined, though it was only once and I may have just gotten lucky.